# Using a pointer after freeing it using free()

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting problems with the following type of code:

```
int* myPointer1 = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
int* myPointer2 = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
free(myPointer1);
myPointer1 = myPointer2;
myPointer1[0] = 3;
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault. What's the problem?

Comment: did you check to make sure the malloc operations were successful? you may be assigning myPointer1 to NULL if not.

Comment: Where do you segfault? At `free(myPointer1)` or on the `myPointer1[0] = 3` ?

Comment: If `malloc` succeeds there should be no segfault. All you are doing is freeing the memory at the original memory location of `myPointer1`, then reassigning `myPointer1` to the location of `myPointer2`. Note, however, if you are going to free that last bit of memory, you will only want to free one of the pointers (i.e. `myPointer1` OR `myPointer2`) since they point to the same address.

Comment: More informations about the used compiler and the compiler flags would e helpful. This could be an optimizer problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't in this code. The snippet you posted appears to be correct, and works fine in isolation.

Comment: The code snippet is correct because it is correct, it is not correct because it works, It could very well work even with a UB and blow up at the time one is least expecting it to.

Comment: I didn't say it was correct because it worked -- I said it appeared to be correct (e.g, it contains no obvious undefined behavior), *and* it works (e.g, I don't get the segmentation fault azphare reported).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct their is nothing wrong in it, but you make a habit of testing the return value of malloc() function, if it is NULL it will create problem in your program, in our case the memory allocation by malloc() function is failed